# Reverse Custom Xcode Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have created a custom segue in my Xcode project that mirrors the built in push segue: my segue brings in another `UIViewController` from the left instead of the right. My question is however, how do I manage to do the "unwind" of this segue?

I know that merely doing an `unwindToViewController` type segue will not work because I am doing a custom segue. So I am not quite sure where to go from here. Here is the code I have for my segue below

**LeftToRightSegue.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LeftToRightSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@property CGRect animationFrame;
@property CGRect sideFrame;

@end
```

**LeftToRightSegue.m**

```
#import "LeftToRightSegue.h"

@implementation LeftToRightSegue

- (void)perform{
    UIViewController *sourceVC = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = self.destinationViewController;

    CGRect sideFrame = destinationVC.view.frame;
    [destinationVC.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-(sourceVC.view.frame.size.width), 0, sourceVC.view.frame.size.width/2, sourceVC.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGRect animationFrame = sourceVC.view.frame;
    sideFrame = destinationVC.view.frame;


    animationFrame.size.width = sourceVC.view.frame.size.width;
    destinationVC.view.alpha = 0;
    [[sourceVC.view superview]addSubview:destinationVC.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         destinationVC.view.frame = animationFrame;
                         destinationVC.view.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         destinationVC.view.alpha = 1;
                         destinationVC.view.frame = animationFrame;

                     }];
}


@end
```

If someone could help me go backwards from this segue (a custom unwind) I would be very appreciative. I have tried to just do the same animation but backwards but I keep receiving errors - not sure why it wont work. If anyone has a suggestion of performing this type of segue differently feel free to let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, so basically you created a custom animation? Or did you bring in the viewController "left" of your current one.

Comment: I animated adding a subview. The problem Im facing is that I can't treat the new view being showed as a "new" ViewController since its just a subview. Unfortunately I can't seem to just reverse the animation to move the current view back left. Not sure what to do lol

Comment: Don't really know how to go about that. You could try and call removeFromSuperView() on it, however, that would not have the animation.